# EPackageRegistrationException error after installing XE2 Update 3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

After installing XE2 update 3 (on fresh XE2 installation) - when I try to launch Delphi XE2 I get the following error

> Exception EPackageRegistrationException in module coreide160.bpl at 00031835.
>   Registration procedure, TogetherReg.IDERegister in package c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\9.0\Bin\TGIDE160.bpl raised exception class EOleSysError: Class no defined, ClassID: {46A75983-3834-436D-8A06-F5BEF75EF067}.
>   Do you want to attempt to load this IDE package the next time Delphi XE2 is run?

How can I solve this error ?

TIA and best regards
Branko

Comment: Contact embarcadero support. They are best placed to deal with this.

Comment: I was, no answer from them (yet) so I'm looking for help here where I often find appropriate advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who could have the same problem: I was install Delphi XE2 and immediate after successfuly instalation I was launch "Check for Updates". This program was install Update 3. According to "Release Notes for XE2 Update 3" Update 3 can be applied over Delphi XE2 with Update 1 and 2. I was not install Update 1 and 2 before I launch "Check for Updates" because I was assume that automatic update cares about required conditions. And my assumption was wrong!

I was solved the problem with advice from Embarcadero support: "The best way (although not quickest) to resolve this would be to do a complete uninstall, making sure "Remove all previous configurations" is checked and then reinstall using the ISO image."