# RAD Studio : Error when launching IDE. How to correct this?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.4.2

Just install the RAD Studio with default option and when I start IDE, I have the following error message.

Any idea ?

One more stuff :
[image: Exception]

**Add**: I try to install on a VM … and it's ok. So it's something on my PM but what?

Comment: Uninstall and try again? Make sure you have the current install sources. Install all updates before running the IDE.

Comment: Have you read this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014583/epackageregistrationexception-error-after-installing-xe2-update-3?

Comment: For installation issues, contact Embarcadero Support. Support is free and available to everyone for installation related problems.

Comment: @KenWhite, yep I open a ticket on support. No answer now 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "just do it" manually with

```
regasm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\bin\Embarcadero.Studio.Modeling.dll"
```

Comment: The risk with this solution is that it was only symptomatic of other problems during installation.  This fix makes the error box go away, but it does not give you any confidence that the rest of the installation is error-free.  You may continue to have unusual errors or issues with the IDE with "hack" fixes like this.

Comment: Perhaps but not seen for the moment … and no answer from Embarcadero Support 

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it wasn't able to register (initialize) a package because the ...Modeling.dll is missing or isn't where it's expected to be.

In Windows 10 in a corporate environment, there could also be some permissions issues, especially if an uninstall / reinstall doesn't fix it.

I'd look at the folder structure and see what's there. Are the BPLs and DLLs where they're expected to be? Do you have full admin rights to the folders? Also, do all of the files have full accessibility to everybody or just the Admin user?

You need to run the installer with elevated permissions for Win 10, although the IT Dept can impose stricter limitations than inside of VMs. This can lead to files being installed but not accessible when you launch the program.

(The last place I was at, we had a separate Admin login from our normal login. We'd use it to install stuff. But component libs would sometimes go into ProgramFiles and sometimes into the User's Documents folder. Perms on those two folder trees were handled differently, and the components would be installed as only visible to the Admin and the IDE couldn't load them up. It was quite a PITA.)